# Hadoop: reducer not getting invoked

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, reducers

I know this is a very basic question but I am not able to find where I am making a mistake. My Reducer is not getting invoked from the driver code. I would greatly appreciate if anyone can help me out.

**My Driver Code**

```java
package com.mycompany.myorg;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser;

public class carsDriver {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, InterruptedException{

        Configuration conf = new Configuration();

        String[] otherArgs = new GenericOptionsParser(conf,args).getRemainingArgs();

        if(otherArgs.length != 2){
            System.err.println("specified input and output path is not correct");
            System.exit(-1);
        }

        // set up the job details

        Job job = new Job(conf,"Cars Avg Fuel Economy");
        job.setJarByClass(carsDriver.class);
        //job.setJobName("Cars Avg Fuel Economy");

        //setup the input and output paths for the MR job
        FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

        // setup of the Mapper, combiner and Reducer classes
        job.setMapperClass(carsMapper.class);
        job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setMapOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

        //job.setCombinerClass(carsCombiner.class);
        job.setReducerClass(carsReducer.class);
        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

        System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true)?0:1);       
    }

}
```

**Mapper Code**

```java
package com.mycompany.myorg;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;

public class carsMapper extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, IntWritable> {

    private Text mapkey = new Text();
    private final static IntWritable mapval = new IntWritable(1);

     public void map(Object key, Text Value,Mapper<Object, Text, Text, IntWritable>.Context context  ) throws IOException, InterruptedException{

         System.out.println("Running the Mapper");
         String items[] = Value.toString().split(",");

         System.out.println(items[2]+" "+Integer.parseInt(items[23].toString()));

         mapkey.set(items[2]);
         mapval.set(Integer.parseInt(items[23].toString()));

         context.write(mapkey, mapval);

     }
}
```

**Reducer Code**

```java
package com.mycompany.myorg;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;

public class carsReducer extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {

    public void reducer(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> value,Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable>.Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        System.out.println("Reducer Code");
        Text redKey = new Text();
        IntWritable redVal = new IntWritable();


        redKey.set(key);

        int sum=0;
        int count=0;
        for(IntWritable val: value){
            sum= sum +val.get();
            count= count + 1;
        }

        redVal.set((sum/count));

        context.write(redKey, redVal);

    }
}
```

Comment: How much are u sure that it's not getting called ? The `syso` statement may not be visible on the console from where the job is getting submitted. Share what `hadoop fs -ls` shows on the outputDirectory of the job.

Comment: I am pretty sure about it because I added system.out prints from mapper and it works and the same does not print from reducer.  Also I even tried to comment the invocation of reducer and still the same output. The output should have been an average of the keys but it is the result of just mapper

Answer (score 0):

After long time debugging the problem I Found that the issue is with the reduce override method.

I used

```
public void reducer
```

instead of

```
public void reduce
```

observe that it should be **reduce** instead of **reducer**.